# .htaccess not working (apache2 | ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: apache2, .htaccess

guys the website is working fine, just the file .htaccess that doesn't work, i googled a lot, already enabled `a2enmod rewrite` and tried a lot of stuff but it didn't work.

obs: i'm using the website example.com as example

this how my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and this how my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

this is how my .htaccess is:

```
#DISALOW DIRECTORY LISTING
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 414 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 502 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /.error.php
```

but it's not disallowing directory listing, and not showing the content in `404.php` when page is not found.

Comment: Please paste .htaccess as well and indicate which command is not working.

Comment: okay, i updated!

Comment: _Aside:_ The `AllowOverride All` directive in the `<Directory />` container _should_ be set to `None`. This potentially opens up your whole server to be parsed for `.htaccess` (except for the two exceptions that follow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current default setup of the [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive causes your problem. If you want to allow override of everything possible by a `.htaccess` file for certain virtual host, you need to change its configuration in a way as this:

```bsh
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html"

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to reload or restart Apache after change of the .conf files.

Comment: i don't know if i'm doing it right, i edited this file ```/etc/apache2/apache2.conf``` to your code, but when i try restart apache2 it gives me an error.

Comment: now it worked thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, @FelipeS.

Comment: Hi, @FelipeS., did you restart Apache? Sometimes browser's cache flushing is also required.